# How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY for UPDATE

Tags: mysql, query, innodb, unique-constraint, duplication

Consider a table of

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
external_id int(11),
number smallint(5),
value varchar(255),
UNIQUE INDEX (external_id, number),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Updating the value of number as

```
UPDATE test SET number=number + 1 WHERE external_id='X'
```

or

```
UPDATE test SET number='Y' WHERE external_id='X'
```

Since external_id-number couple is unique, it will not update if the new value of number exists.

How can I use something like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` to increase the value of `number` by `number + 1` to reach an available value according to the UNIQUE Constraint and complete the `UPDATE` task?

Comment: Do you want to update all rows that have `external_id='X'` by increasing the `number` by 1? Or just one row is to be updated?

Answer (score 5):

First a sample table

```
mysql> drop database if exists ali;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> create database ali;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use ali;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE test
    -> (
    -> id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> external_id int(11),
    -> number smallint(5),
    -> value varchar(255),
    -> UNIQUE INDEX (external_id, number),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's insert an initial row and SELECT it back

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (200,15,'Y')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + 1;SELECT * FROM test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     15 | Y     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let's insert the same thing again

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (200,15,'Y')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + 1;SELECT * FROM test;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.10 sec)

+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     16 | Y     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK let's try the value column at the same time

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (201,15,'X')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> number = number + 1,value = VALUES(value);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     16 | Y     |
|  5 |         201 |     15 | X     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (201,15,'X')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> number = number + 1,value = VALUES(value);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     16 | Y     |
|  5 |         201 |     16 | X     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This time change value and number

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (202,15,'Z')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> number = number + 1,
    -> value = VALUES(value);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     16 | Y     |
|  5 |         201 |     16 | X     |
|  8 |         202 |     15 | Z     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (external_id,number,value)
    -> VALUES (202,15,'A')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> number = number + 1,
    -> value = VALUES(value);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
| id | external_id | number | value |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 |         200 |     16 | Y     |
|  5 |         201 |     16 | X     |
|  8 |         202 |     16 | A     |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Hope this helps.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I really like your way of answering and I deeply appreciate it. However, this is the first method came into my mind. The problem is that UPDATE KEY is not recursive. In you last INSERT if you already have number 16, it will not change 15 to 17 (next available value). It will only try 16, and will fail due to duplicate key.