# How to code something like 'Update on duplicate key update to something else'?

Tags: mariadb, update, duplication

As part of dealing with the UK's GDPA 'right to be forgotten' in a small database I want to update the (autoinc) PK of a row in table 'member' to an obfuscated value and let it cascade down through the FKs in related tables, such as the dates they held certain positions.

If I then set the names of the member in table 'member' to empty strings I can still use my related tables, for example to determine that there was someone holding a certain position at a certain time but I will no longer be able to ascertain either the name or the id of the person who held it, which is what I want.

I have written a simple a UDF obfuscate_id() that takes a positive integer ID and returns a negative ID calculated by combining the id passed with a random number.

```
FUNCTION obfuscate_id(id INT) RETURNS INT
COMMENT 'returns the negative version of the id passed, obfuscated by a random number'

BEGIN
  DECLARE result INT;
  SET result =  (FLOOR(RAND(id)*10000) + id ) * -1;
  IF result > 0  THEN -- ensures result is -ve even if called with a -ve parameter
     SET result = result * -1; 
  END IF;  
  RETURN  result;
END;
```

And I am using the sql

```
UPDATE member
SET  member_id = obfuscate_id(member_id)
WHERE member_id = 1234;
```

However, this might generate a negative id that already exists from a previous update of another member_id. If so I want to set it to something else, maybe by obfuscating the id again as in

```
SET  member_id = obfuscate_id(obfuscate_id(member_id));
```

Is there a simple way, like ON DUPLICATE KEY ... to check if the value I am about to update to already exists and if so update to something else?

I did look at
[how-to-use-on-duplicate-key-for-update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15589/how-to-use-on-duplicate-key-for-update)
and
[update-on-duplicate-key-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466647/update-on-duplicate-key-update)
and
[mysql-update-with-on-duplicate-key-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540270/mysql-update-with-on-duplicate-key-update)
but am no wiser

*I would add that given the size of table 'member' and the particular application, even the first update is going to be a very rare occurrence, so the chance of having any obfuscated IDs is extremely slim, let alone duplicate ones, but I'd like to cover the eventuality if I can.*

Comment: Please provide the structure of your member table...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler / easier to just choose a random number who's range is outside your current range of values in `member`? E.g. something like `(FLOOR(RAND(id)) * -1) + (SELECT MIN(id) FROM member)` roughly speaking? (There's probably a simpler way to achieve the same outcome even.)

Comment: Sounds like you need a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: @Vérace. I don't really see how that would help you to answer my question. Suffice to say that its a InnoDB table with PK  `member_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and then a couple of dozen VARCHAR data fields such as first_name, surname, dob, etc, and ten or so TINYINT fields used as Booleans to record things like is_full_time_student or prefers_home_phone_in handbook, All that data I can set to null so the member_id cannot be used to retrieve anything anyway.

Comment: @J.D. Yes, there might be something in that idea as even if `(FLOOR(RAND(id)) * -1)1 produced a result that I had calculated previously the final member_id should still be different that any I've used before. I'll investigate the code.

Comment: @user2834566 Right, my example/ pseudo-code should always guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @Rick James Possibly, but the logic of what the trigger would do is the same as me simply executing a procedure to do it when I want to. After all, I would have to do something to the record, such as update a field to an empty string, to fire the trigger in the first place. I might as well alter the member_id at the same time

Comment: If anyone is familiar with the UK's GDPA maybe they can tell me if I even need to do this anyway. If I delete all personal data related to a member_id, such as name, address etc then surely the member_id has no meaning on it's own. Agreed it might link to another table that tells me someone with that member_id was once the Hon. secretary or the Hon. Librarian between certain dates but since I won't be able to find out any personal data about them is it even necessary to alter the member_id at all?

Comment: @J.D. Do you want to put that as an answer as I think it will work. Then I can accept it.

Comment: @user2834566 - I'd go with an UPDATE solution... why change it to remove it anyway? Keep the IDs - put in "Anonymised" for surname for example - or "Redacted" for address. You could provide a contact phone... yours or your office's - in case of enquiries... Just NULL everything identifiable - I read [this](https://www.gov.uk/data-protection#:~:text=The%20Data%20Protection%20Act%202018,organisations%2C%20businesses%20or%20the%20government.&text=Everyone%20responsible%20for%20using%20personal,used%20fairly%2C%20lawfully%20and%20transparently) - seems fairly similar to EU's GDPR!

Comment: @ Vérace, That's exactly the law I'm trying to implement. Its great on rhetoric but not so good on detail. However I'm tending to think I can do exactly what you suggest

Comment: @user2834566 Sounds good, just made an answer. Will try to add more details / help when I get a chance. I'll need to catch up on the rest of the comment thread here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler / easier to just choose a random number who's range is outside your current range of values in the `member` table? E.g. something like `(FLOOR(RAND(id)) * -1) + (SELECT MIN(id) FROM member)` (semi-pseudocode)?

Comment: That would work and it answers my original question so I'll accept it. Thank you. But thinking about it further, I might also consider the suggestion by  Vérace and just not bother to change the id at all.

Comment: @user2834566 Just caught up on the other details. **GDPR** is a tough thing and grey area to support. Many people fail to realize that even if they remove the user's data at their request from the database, they still aren't fully following **GDPR** until they go back and delete that data from every database backup and database server backup they have too. It's actually a near impossible task to be 100% **GDPR** compliant until the **EU** makes a ruling that those auxillary copies of the data don't matter. Not sure if you're doing database or server backups. That being said, to work towards...

Comment: ... **GDPR** compliancy at least, I'd recommend Verace's solution even in addition to mine. Obfuscating the actual data with an `UPDATE` either by randomizing it or `NULLing` it out is a good first step.

Comment: I keep daily backups on my PC and every now and then I delete all those over a month old . The server keeps one weekly and one monthly backup. Apparently backups are OK as you are not processing the data in them. That is until you use one of them to restore from. At that point you are once again 'processing' the data and so must have somehow already erased the personal data from the backup. - and also from any old copies of emails sent or received, any old documents, electronic or printed  etc. I generally get the feeling that those who designed the GDPA have never also designed a database!

Comment: @user2834566 Agreed, don't think the people who came up with **GDPR** / **GDPA** were very technologically savvy. I do agree, I think general accepted practice in the developer community with the backups is that they're *OK* baring they're not in use. But I think the actual language of **GDPR** and the lack of an official ruling makes it a grey area officially, currently. But that's one for the lawyers whenever that bridge is eventually crossed.